# Cannot connect to SQL server from python using Active Directory Authentication

Tags: python, sql-server

I am using pymssql library to connect python to Sql Server. I can connect using windows/sql server authentication. I want to connect using Active Directory Authentication.

Tried the below connection string. But it fails with error :

```
unexpected keyword authentication


conn = pymssql.connect(server='adventureworks.database.windows.net', authentication = 'Active Directory Password',user='username@server.com',password='Enterpasswordhere', database='dbo')
```

Answer (score 7):

Update 2019-11-01: The "sign-in assistant" appears to be part of Windows Essentials, which has been [discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Essentials#Deprecation) and is no longer available for download.

---

You can do this using ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server and the Microsoft Sign-In assistant if you are on a Windows machine.

1. install ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server
   https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=53339
2. install sign-in assistant *(link broken)*
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234947
3. test connection

   import pyodbc
   server = **servername ending in windows.net**
   database = **database**
   username = **username**
   password = **password**
   tablename = **tablename**

   driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}’
   cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=‘ + driver +
                     ';PORT=1433;SERVER=‘ + server +
                     ';PORT=1443;DATABASE=‘+database+
                     ';UID='+username+
                    ';PWD='+ password +
                     ';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword’)

   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 * from ” + tablename)
   row = cursor.fetchone()

   while row:

   print str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1])
      row = cursor.fetchone()

Answer (score 0):

[Note that pymssql.connect does not have an 'authentication' parameter](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html#functions). You are passing it that as a named arg, which is invalid, and the reason you see your error.

See [this example](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html#connecting-using-windows-authentication) for connecting using windows authentication:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(
    host=r'dbhostname\myinstance',
    user=r'companydomain\username',
    password=PASSWORD,
    database='DatabaseOfInterest'
)
```

Comment: Yeah, the above examples  work only for windows and Sql server Authentications. I want to use Active Directory Password Authentication to access the Database.