# Sqlalchemy - Connecting to Microsoft Azure - Active directory Password

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

I was connecting to MS SQL with sqlalchemy using bwlow code and now it has been migrated to azure cloud. I tried the chaging the values code but i think its not the proper way to connect ActiveDirectoryPassword

```
    import sqlalchemy
        from sqlalchemy import event, create_engine
# OLD connection string 
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://" + "username" + ":" + "passkey" + "@" + "server" + "/" + "Database" + "?driver=SQL+Server"

        @event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
        def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
            if executemany:
                cursor.fast_executemany = True
                cursor.commit()

    # New connection string (for Active directory connection - not working)
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://" + "abc@domain.com" + ":" + "passkey" + "@" + "xxxx-svsql1.database.windows.net" + "/" + "Database" + "?driver=SQL+Server" + "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword")
```

Please note I was able to successfully able to connect using pyodbc but not able to do that using sqlalchemy by following

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118470/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-from-python-using-active-directory-authentication/44076936#44076936)

Please guide

Comment: Did your problem solved now?  If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried this code and connect to my Azure SQL DATABASE with Active directory Password successfully.

```
import sqlalchemy
import urllib
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import event

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:***.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=db_name;UID=***@***.com;PWD=***;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
       if executemany:
            cursor.fast_executemany = True
            cursor.commit()

conn=engine.connect()
print(conn)
```

Replace the `UID` with your AD account.

For more details, please see the this document: [Connecting to PyODBC](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#connecting-to-pyodbc).

My python version is Python 3.7.3.

Hope this helps.