# Is allowing Azure Services to be turned on as a firewall rule inside my Azure Database a security issue?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have the "Allow Azure Services to access this server" option turned on for my Azure Database. The reason for me having turned it on is because I have a Function App that accesses the database to do inserts etc.

My question is, is having this option turned on a security issue at all? If it is, what is the best practice method to keep my database secure while still being able to access it myself through my Function App.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are connecting to your SQL databases using username/password combination, there's always a security risk in case your username/password are leaked.

A better approach would be to use [`Managed Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview). What you will do is assign an identity to your Function app and then allow that identity to connect to your database. That way only your Function App will be able to connect to your database. You would still need to keep "Allow Azure Services to access this server" option turned on though.

Please see this link on connecting an Azure WebApp to a SQL Database using Managed Identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cef%2Cdotnet

Comment: Yes, I am connecting to my database through a username/password combination. I'm concealing those values through the use of Key Vault. I have a system assigned managed identity turned on already for my function app and added an access policy to my Key Vault so that it could connect. I guess that would provide enough security because in order for someone to get the username and password they'd have to get access to my key vault, which they shouldn't be able to access at all because they would need an access policy. Let me know if I'm wrong about that. Regardless, I wasn't aware that I could...

Comment: add a similar thing like an access policy to a database. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cef%2Cdotnet#grant-permissions-to-managed-identity. By directly connecting to your DB through Managed Identity, you can bypass reading the connection string from KeyVault.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I don't think I can fully remove connection string from my code and just use a managed identity, because I'm using pandas methods to do things that require to pass an SQL Alchemy engine connection, which takes a connection string to create. But thank you, again.

Comment: What’s the underlying library/SDK you’re using to connect to the database? Please check if that supports Azure AD based authentication.

Comment: I'm using SQL Alchemy to connect to the database. I will check to see if that's an option

Comment: I'm checking for references, found this but there is still a connection string involved here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582031/sqlalchemy-connecting-to-microsoft-azure-active-directory-password