# How to use user / password auth for Active Directory account with pyodbc on linux

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, pymssql

I have to connect to SQL Server using pyodbc on linux. The account is an Active Directory account. Using pymssql, I can connect by specifying `corp\svc_account`. But on pyodbc, the connection fails.

With pyodbc it seems we can only use trusted connection OR user / password. And user / password only works for SQL Server auth - not Active Directory.

But with pymssql it seems we can connect using an Active Directory auth with a user / password.

Is there some way I can use my Active Directory credentials with pyodbc?

I don't want to install kerberos client either.

Comment: Have you tried [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076936/390122)?

Comment: If you want to "use my Active Directory credentials" why can't you just use `Trusted_Connection=yes` ?

Comment: @GordThompson Trusted_connection only works when you area already authenticated through kerberos.  I can't use kerberos.

Comment: If the domain has the Kerberos I think you can't connect using the AD Credential because, I suppose, the connection trying directly instead of kerberos ticket. See the [FAQ pymssql](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/faq.html#cannot-connect-to-sql-server) where mention kerberos and the module compilation.

Comment: I see from the edit to your question that you are trying to connect from Linux. In that case you'll probably need to connect using FreeTDS, either via pyodbc + FreeTDS ODBC or via pymssql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up PYODBC to use the FreeTDS driver instead of microsoft odbc driver, and you have to make sure that you specify all the correct parameters for your connection.

Getting FreeTDS to work with pyodbc can be a little confusing and tricky.

1. Make sure you have FreeTDS installed.
2. Find your odbc driver config file (`odbcinst.ini`).

```
❯ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/<user>/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

In my case the file is located at `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini`.

3. Ensure your driver config file has an entry for the FreeTDS driver.

In my case, on a mac, my `odbcinst.ini` has this entry:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=TD Driver (MSSQL)
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
FileUsage=1
```

When you specify a `driver` in pyodbc, this is the file where it looks it up.

4. Now it should work.

```py
import pyodbc
cnx = pyodbc.connect(
    server="myserver.com",
    database="mydb",
    user="domain\user",
    password="mypassword",
    port="1433",
    driver='FreeTDS',
    TDS_Version='7.4',
)
```

Some notes:

1. With an active directory account, make sure to specify the domain in the `user` field.
2. Params like `TDS_Version` are not respected in `odbcinst.ini`.  So if you get an error such as `[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)`, you might need to specify the `TDS_Version` in `connect`.